# How do I position an SVG behind an anchor element so that their bottoms are aligned?

Tags: html, css, svg, anchor

I have a very simple test website where I want to place an SVG image behind an anchor element and some other elements above it but have the bottoms of the SVG image and the paragraph element bottom-aligned.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

footer {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  padding: 1.25%;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt
  ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit
  esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<p>
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
  animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
  est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
  voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt
  ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit
  esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<p>
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
  animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
  est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
  voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
<br><br>

<footer>Shamar's Domestic Cleaning Services</footer>
<a href="example@gmail.com">Built by Riverstone Technologies UK © 2023</a>

<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="wave" style="transform:rotate(0deg); transition: 0.3s" viewBox="0 0 1440 490" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="sw-gradient-0" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
                <stop stop-color="rgba(161, 11, 255, 1)" offset="0%" />
                <stop stop-color="rgba(161, 11, 255, 1)" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path style="transform:translate(0, 0px); opacity:1" fill="url(#sw-gradient-0)"
            d="M0,343L30,318.5C60,294,120,245,180,187.8C240,131,300,65,360,73.5C420,82,480,163,540,171.5C600,180,660,114,720,138.8C780,163,840,278,900,310.3C960,343,1020,294,1080,253.2C1140,212,1200,180,1260,147C1320,114,1380,82,1440,114.3C1500,147,1560,245,1620,302.2C1680,359,1740,376,1800,383.8C1860,392,1920,392,1980,375.7C2040,359,2100,327,2160,294C2220,261,2280,229,2340,187.8C2400,147,2460,98,2520,65.3C2580,33,2640,16,2700,32.7C2760,49,2820,98,2880,163.3C2940,229,3000,310,3060,294C3120,278,3180,163,3240,98C3300,33,3360,16,3420,57.2C3480,98,3540,196,3600,269.5C3660,343,3720,392,3780,400.2C3840,408,3900,376,3960,367.5C4020,359,4080,376,4140,392C4200,408,4260,425,4290,432.8L4320,441L4320,490L4290,490C4260,490,4200,490,4140,490C4080,490,4020,490,3960,490C3900,490,3840,490,3780,490C3720,490,3660,490,3600,490C3540,490,3480,490,3420,490C3360,490,3300,490,3240,490C3180,490,3120,490,3060,490C3000,490,2940,490,2880,490C2820,490,2760,490,2700,490C2640,490,2580,490,2520,490C2460,490,2400,490,2340,490C2280,490,2220,490,2160,490C2100,490,2040,490,1980,490C1920,490,1860,490,1800,490C1740,490,1680,490,1620,490C1560,490,1500,490,1440,490C1380,490,1320,490,1260,490C1200,490,1140,490,1080,490C1020,490,960,490,900,490C840,490,780,490,720,490C660,490,600,490,540,490C480,490,420,490,360,490C300,490,240,490,180,490C120,490,60,490,30,490L0,490Z" />
    </svg>
```

Here is a rendering of what the website looks like right now;
[image: Website with SVG]

However as you can see the wavy purple SVG is not bottom-aligned with the anchor tag above it nor is it behind it(which I know how use by setting the svg's z-index to -1).

Comment: Note, don't add an XML Declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>`) to the `<head>` of an HTML document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a parent element that contains your entire page (here I've added a `div` and given it the class `page-container`).

You can then position your SVG relative to this parent using `position: absolute`. From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.php):

> `position: absolute` The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

First, you'll therefore need to add `position: relative;` to the parent element's styles to make it the **first positioned ancestor**.

Then, since you want the bottom of your SVG to be aligned with the bottom of parent (and therefore its last static sibling, the anchor tag), use `bottom: 0`. This property defines the distance from the bottom of the parent where you want the SVG to appear.

Here's your full code snippet with these changes put in:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

footer {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  padding: 1.25%;
}

.page-container {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  <p>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  <p>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  </p>
  <br><br>

  <footer>Shamar's Domestic Cleaning Services</footer>
  <a href="example@gmail.com">Built by Riverstone Technologies UK © 2023</a>

  <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="wave" style="transform:rotate(0deg); transition: 0.3s" viewBox="0 0 1440 490" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="sw-gradient-0" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
                <stop stop-color="rgba(161, 11, 255, 1)" offset="0%" />
                <stop stop-color="rgba(161, 11, 255, 1)" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path style="transform:translate(0, 0px); opacity:1" fill="url(#sw-gradient-0)"
            d="M0,343L30,318.5C60,294,120,245,180,187.8C240,131,300,65,360,73.5C420,82,480,163,540,171.5C600,180,660,114,720,138.8C780,163,840,278,900,310.3C960,343,1020,294,1080,253.2C1140,212,1200,180,1260,147C1320,114,1380,82,1440,114.3C1500,147,1560,245,1620,302.2C1680,359,1740,376,1800,383.8C1860,392,1920,392,1980,375.7C2040,359,2100,327,2160,294C2220,261,2280,229,2340,187.8C2400,147,2460,98,2520,65.3C2580,33,2640,16,2700,32.7C2760,49,2820,98,2880,163.3C2940,229,3000,310,3060,294C3120,278,3180,163,3240,98C3300,33,3360,16,3420,57.2C3480,98,3540,196,3600,269.5C3660,343,3720,392,3780,400.2C3840,408,3900,376,3960,367.5C4020,359,4080,376,4140,392C4200,408,4260,425,4290,432.8L4320,441L4320,490L4290,490C4260,490,4200,490,4140,490C4080,490,4020,490,3960,490C3900,490,3840,490,3780,490C3720,490,3660,490,3600,490C3540,490,3480,490,3420,490C3360,490,3300,490,3240,490C3180,490,3120,490,3060,490C3000,490,2940,490,2880,490C2820,490,2760,490,2700,490C2640,490,2580,490,2520,490C2460,490,2400,490,2340,490C2280,490,2220,490,2160,490C2100,490,2040,490,1980,490C1920,490,1860,490,1800,490C1740,490,1680,490,1620,490C1560,490,1500,490,1440,490C1380,490,1320,490,1260,490C1200,490,1140,490,1080,490C1020,490,960,490,900,490C840,490,780,490,720,490C660,490,600,490,540,490C480,490,420,490,360,490C300,490,240,490,180,490C120,490,60,490,30,490L0,490Z" />
    </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the bottom of the SVG is still not aligned with the bottom of the anchor element.

Comment: @IsaacNewtonGravity Do you want it aligned with the bottom of the `a` element (as in the snippet above) or with the bottom of the last `p` element?

Comment: The anchor element

Comment: @IsaacNewtonGravity In the above snippet, the bottom of the `svg` (the purple shape) is aligned with the bottom of the anchor element (the link which says *Built by Riverstone Technologies UK © 2023*). Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: There is quite a gap between them.

Comment: @IsaacNewtonGravity I've added an image of the result from my code snippet. The anchor and svg look aligned to me. Is this what you see?

Comment: Yes that’s perfect! Many thanks. I had the closing div tag in the wrong place. Please can you explain why that works? Thanks.

Comment: @IsaacNewtonGravity Great! I've added some more detail to my answer, including a link to the w3schools page on the `position` property, hopefully this makes sense now. Note also that you can use the button "Run code snippet" to see the result of someone's code straight on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to **add SVG as a background** to the footer element html then move your text around with margin.

First you need to convert your SVG code to CSS.
You can use this [tool](https://svgwiz.com/). I have edited your code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.25%;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

footer {

   background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="wave" style="transform:rotate(0deg); transition: 0.3s" viewBox="0 0 1440 490" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient id="sw-gradient-0" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0"%3E%3Cstop stop-color="rgba(161, 11, 255, 1)" offset="0%25" /%3E%3Cstop stop-color="rgba(161, 11, 255, 1)" offset="100%25" /%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cpath style="transform:translate(0, 0px); opacity:1" fill="url(%23sw-gradient-0)" d="M0,343L30,318.5C60,294,120,245,180,187.8C240,131,300,65,360,73.5C420,82,480,163,540,171.5C600,180,660,114,720,138.8C780,163,840,278,900,310.3C960,343,1020,294,1080,253.2C1140,212,1200,180,1260,147C1320,114,1380,82,1440,114.3C1500,147,1560,245,1620,302.2C1680,359,1740,376,1800,383.8C1860,392,1920,392,1980,375.7C2040,359,2100,327,2160,294C2220,261,2280,229,2340,187.8C2400,147,2460,98,2520,65.3C2580,33,2640,16,2700,32.7C2760,49,2820,98,2880,163.3C2940,229,3000,310,3060,294C3120,278,3180,163,3240,98C3300,33,3360,16,3420,57.2C3480,98,3540,196,3600,269.5C3660,343,3720,392,3780,400.2C3840,408,3900,376,3960,367.5C4020,359,4080,376,4140,392C4200,408,4260,425,4290,432.8L4320,441L4320,490L4290,490C4260,490,4200,490,4140,490C4080,490,4020,490,3960,490C3900,490,3840,490,3780,490C3720,490,3660,490,3600,490C3540,490,3480,490,3420,490C3360,490,3300,490,3240,490C3180,490,3120,490,3060,490C3000,490,2940,490,2880,490C2820,490,2760,490,2700,490C2640,490,2580,490,2520,490C2460,490,2400,490,2340,490C2280,490,2220,490,2160,490C2100,490,2040,490,1980,490C1920,490,1860,490,1800,490C1740,490,1680,490,1620,490C1560,490,1500,490,1440,490C1380,490,1320,490,1260,490C1200,490,1140,490,1080,490C1020,490,960,490,900,490C840,490,780,490,720,490C660,490,600,490,540,490C480,490,420,490,360,490C300,490,240,490,180,490C120,490,60,490,30,490L0,490Z" /%3E%3C/svg%3E') ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 
  background-size: 100Vw;
  position: relative;
   bottom: 0;
}


.svg {
  position: relative;

  width:50%;
 left: 27%;
  bottom: 0;
}


.cope {
width:100%;
  margin-top:25%;
 
   bottom: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  <p>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
 

  <footer>
    <div class="cope">
      <div class="svg">
    <p>Shamar's Domestic Cleaning Services</p>
    <p><a href="example@gmail.com">Built by Riverstone Technologies UK © 2023</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
 </footer>

  

</div>
```